# Prove existence of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that that for a non-zero positive sequence $a_m \rightarrow 0$ and arbitrary  real $t$ there exists a sequence of integers $\{ k_m \}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_m k_m \rightarrow t$.

Comment: This statement doesn't hold. Let $a_m = 0$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$, then you got $a_m \to 0$ but you wont find a sequece $(k_m)_{m \in \mathbb N}$ with $a_mk_m \to 1$.

Comment: Thank you. I missed to say that $\{a_m\}_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ is non-zero sequence. I will fix it.

Comment: You must suppose the $a_m$ are eventually *all* positive or or eventually all negative.

Comment: Oh.. I was not concentrated! Thank you. Indeed, in my problem, the sequence is a sequence of matrix norms... Fixed again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $[x]$ defined as $[x[\leq x< [x[]+1$ and $[x]\in \mathbb{Z}$, and if $a_m>0$ for all $m$, take $k_m=[\frac{t}{a_m}]$. We have then $ \frac{t}{a_m}=k_m+\varepsilon_m$ with $\varepsilon_m\in [0,1[$, hence $1=a_m k_m+a_m\varepsilon_m$, and as $a_m\to 0$, it is clear that $\varepsilon_m a_m\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought of this $k_m$ but didn't represent $t/a_m$ as a sum of its integer part and fraction part.